# Why doesn't jQuery wrap new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `$new` `div` is not wrapped with the following code:

```
var $new = $('<div>test</div>');
$('form').append($new.wrap("<div class='new'></div>")) ;
```

What 's wrong with that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** We were thinking wrong about `$new.wrap()` won't work because the **html in $new is not in the HTML DOM Tree** but its just a variable which contains html elements. This was just wrong as per discussion with @A. Wolff.

However, the following solutions are not bad.

```
var $new = $('<div class="test">test</div>');
$('form').append($new)//first append
   .find('.test')//find appended element
   .wrap('<div class="new" />');//then wrap to appended element
```

Or, simply you can do like this if you don't want to give a class on appended element:

```
$new.appendTo('form')//I am still on $new (no need to find anything)
 .wrap('<div class="new" />');//So, I can wrap to $new
```

---

Now, to stick with your code you need to return the parent element as @A. Wolff mentioned:

```
$('form').append($new.wrap("<div class='new'></div>").parent());
```

I will explain a bit about this `why actually I need to return the parent element?`:

```
$new.wrap('<div class="new" />');//I am still in $new not in the .new element
.append($new.wrap('<div class="new" />');//append the $new not the .new object
```

So, the wrap method works as expected but append() method appends the returning html and that's why in `$new.wrap('<div class="new" />')` the returning html is  `$('<div>test</div>');` but not wrapped object. And you will not get what you expected. So, to get the expected result, we can use:

```
$('form').append(
   $new.wrap('<div class="new" />') //I am returning $new
   .parent()//Now, I am returning '.new' 
);//now .new object is appended to the form
```

This is how append method works!

Comment: Following your edit, you make my answer a dupe... :)

Comment: Sorry, but my connection was slow so edit was slow, so there are 4-5 edits for little sentences too, but din't copy the answer.

Comment: `din't copy the answer` Ya, i didn't mean that and i believe you of course. :)

Comment: Thanks. I was also searching for wrap method to say exactly what I mean that wrap method can only work with dom-tree(as in my answer), but couldn't find documentation anywhere, so it cause me little slow too.

Comment: And here relevant bug set as fixed (7 years ago): https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3828   Not sure what to think about it...  That's said, you get my vote for your well explained answer ;)

Comment: Ok, we were finally completly wrong. The issue is that `wrap()` to keep chaining return the element itself, so here, we should return the wrapping element, means the parent: `$('form').append($new.wrap("<div class='new'></div>").parent()) ;` then it works as expected

Answer (score 3):

`wrap()` returns element itself, so you need to return the `parent` element:

```
$('form').append($new.wrap("<div class='new'></div>").parent());
```

Or inverse your logic using `appendTo()`:

```
$new.appendTo('form').wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
```

Comment: Amazed to see the fix how you debug this ^

Comment: By thinking it twice regarding what returns `wrap()` method. And after all, that was just a logic issue... ;)